# Suddenly, abruptly Vs out of the blue

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was wondering if someone could let me know which choice works better in the following self-made sentence below. (I need to know the most natural choice here.)

Imagine someone is teaching driving someone else and is going to say the point that you have not release the clutch when it is in the gear suddenly.

> - Don’t release the clutch............
>
> a) suddenly
>
> b) abruptly
>
> c) out of the blue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either abruptly or suddenly could be used. "Abruptly" may be the best choice as it also suggests something undesirable. The release of a clutch should normally be smooth.

"Out of the blue" has the wrong sense. It refers to something unexpected, but a driver would be expected to release the clutch many times during a journey.